# How to create atomic from unsafe memory in Rust

Tags: rust

I am learning unsafe Rust and trying to create an atomic backed by a pointer to some unsafe memory (e.g. a buffer from C or memory mapped file).

I tried this:

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicI64, Ordering};

fn main() -> () {
    let mut v = vec![1i64, 2i64];
    let ptr = &mut v[0] as *mut i64;
    unsafe {
        let a = std::mem::transmute::<*mut i64, AtomicI64>(ptr);
        println!("{}", a.load(Ordering::Relaxed));
    }
}
```

But it prints the address of the pointer (e.g. `2119547391296`) instead of `1`.

What is the correct way to create an atomic located in some external buffer?

I want the same functionality such as e.g. C# `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref *(long*)ptr, ...)`, so maybe there are other ways to get lock-free sync primitives in Rust?

**Update:**

It looks like I need `std::intrinsics::{*}`, but they are not available in stable Rust.

**Update 2:**

This compiles and prints `1 2 2` (i.e. `v[0]` is updated as expected via `AtomicI64` created via pointer cast and then dereferencing `AtomicI64` via `& *ptr`). But is this correct?

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicI64, Ordering};

fn main() -> () {
    let v = vec![1i64, 2i64];
    let ptr = &v[0] as *const i64 as *const AtomicI64;

    unsafe {
        let a = & *ptr;
        println!("{}", a.load(Ordering::SeqCst));
        a.fetch_add(1i64, Ordering::SeqCst);
        println!("{}", a.load(Ordering::SeqCst));
        println!("{}", v[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation for `AtomicI64`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicI64.html) says this:

> This type has the same in-memory representation as the underlying integer type, i64.

However, you're trying to transmute a *pointer* to an `i64` to an `AtomicI64`:

```rust
unsafe {
  let a = std::mem::transmute::<*mut i64, AtomicI64>(ptr);
  //               is a pointer ^^^^^^^^
  //                                      ^^^^^^^^^ is not a pointer
}
```

Instead, you'd need to transmute `*mut i64` into a pointer or reference to `AtomicI64`.

This can be implemented like this (safe and unsafe variants):

```rust
// if we have a mut reference, it must have unqiue ownership over the
// referenced data, so we can safely cast that into an immutable reference
// to AtomicI64
fn make_atomic_i64<'a>(src: &'a mut i64) -> &'a AtomicI64 {
  unsafe {
    &*(src as *mut i64 as *const AtomicI64)
  }
}

// if we have a mut pointer, we have no guarantee of ownership or lifetime, and
// therefore it's unsafe to cast into an immutable reference to AtomicI64
unsafe fn make_ptr_atomic_i64<'a>(src: *mut i64) -> &'a AtomicI64 {
  &*(src as *const AtomicI64)
}
```

---

[Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6a81e661cd16c3a499c01f03ecd1c901):

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicI64, Ordering};

fn main() -> () {
    // declare underlying buffer
    let mut v = vec![1i64, 2i64];

    {
        // get atomic safely
        let atomic = make_atomic_i64(&mut v[0]);

        // try to access atomic
        println!("{}", atomic.swap(10, Ordering::Relaxed)); // = 1
    }

    unsafe {
        // get atomic unsafely
        let atomic = make_ptr_atomic_i64(&mut v[0] as *mut i64);

        // try to access atomic
        println!("{}", atomic.swap(100, Ordering::Relaxed)); // = 10
    }

    // print final state of variable
    println!("{}", v[0]); // = 100
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You answered 30 min after my Update 2 edit (so I assume you've seen it) where I did basically the same thing with the same reasoning about layout, but even without transmute and using `as *const i64 as *const AtomicI64`. So you confirm that this is not UB? Or transmute with lifetime is better/correct vs `as` cast?

Comment: @V.B. I didn't see your update before after I answered, but yes, seems like you came to the same conclusion. Yes, as far as I can tell it shouldn't be: `AtomicI64` always has the same memory representation as `i64`, as do pointers and references ([source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html)). As long as the data is only accessed atomically, I don't see any reason why it should be undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to attach lifetime to `as` pointer cast?

Comment: @V.B. You can't do it with the `as` cast, but you can do it when dereferencing: `let x: &'a AtomicI64 = &*x;`

Comment: I missed some deleted comment by @trentcl. Why pointer cast via `as` is preferred over transmute?

Comment: Regarding `make_atomic_pointer`, you might as well remove `'a` and have the function return a `'static` pointer. Since the lifetime is unconstrained anyway...

Comment: @MatthieuM. Using `'static` in cases like this should be done with care, as you risk having the returned reference outlive the data and not being able to catch it compile-time, as you otherwise would have. And setting a lifetime like this when casting from a pointer seems to be to be convention, e.g. with [`std::slice::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html) doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

[`AtomicPtr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicPtr.html) will do the job. You can only construct it from a mutable pointer because it must own the data pointed to.

If you have a shared/sharable raw pointer (a const one), it cannot be atomic by design. If you want to share a pointer, it must be an `AtomicPtr` behind an `Arc`.

Just as a reminder, mutable reference/pointer equals unique, and const reference/pointer equals shared. If you break this rule, your program is undefined behavior.

Comment: But if I do `let x = AtomicPtr::new(ptr);*(x.load(Ordering::Relaxed))` then it seems that atomic access is to the pointer itself, not to the `i64` content? Dereferencing the content is not atomic.

Comment: I mean the second dereferencing using `*` from `*mut i64` that I get from `load` is not atomic. The use case is that pointer remains stable, but I do `compare_and_swap` on the `i64` value.

Comment: @V.B. I may be wrong, but I think that you will not have any issue dereferencing the pointer because it is not shared. Note that it is not clone. In unsafe code, it's up to you to not break this rule.

Comment: I'm in unsafe land and doing lock-free sync via shared memory from different processes, not even threads. So there is concurrent access to the `i64` content of the pointer.

Comment: @V.B. That's another question. I'm not even sure that this is feasible in Rust...

Comment: It should be possible from unsafe Rust, but maybe not implemented. CAS over shared memory is pretty common though since some OSes do not even have cross-process named mutexes.

Comment: I would use an `*mut AtomicI64` inside an `AtomicPtr`, but that wouldn't be lock free, and I don't even know if it is safe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196376/discussion-between-french-boiethios-and-v-b).