# How to share pthread synchronisation primitives between C++ and Rust?

Tags: c++, multithreading, rust, synchronization, ipc

I have a C++ program and a Rust program, and between them I have successfully got them talking over POSIX shared memory ([C++](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) and [rust](https://crates.io/crates/shared_memory)).

What I am now trying to do is synchronise them. I already managed to create a working, but inefficient, primitive system using an atomic bool (creating the `AtomicBool` on the rust side [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57013795)).

However, I would really like to use a mutex/condvar to synchronise between the threads, and this is where I am stuck.

I seem to be able to initialise the C++ side of it, following [this example](https://github.com/goldsborough/ipc-bench/blob/master/source/shm-sync/shm-sync-common.c#L8) pretty much word for word.

I have attempted to translate it directly into rust:

```
    let raw_shm = shm.get_shm();

    let mut mtx_attrs = MaybeUninit::<nix::libc::pthread_mutexattr_t>::uninit();
    if unsafe { nix::libc::pthread_mutexattr_init(mtx_attrs.as_mut_ptr()) } != 0 {
        panic!("failed to create mtx_attrs");
    };
    let mtx_attrs = unsafe { mtx_attrs.assume_init() };

    let mut cond_attrs = MaybeUninit::<nix::libc::pthread_condattr_t>::uninit();
    if unsafe { nix::libc::pthread_condattr_init(cond_attrs.as_mut_ptr()) } != 0 {
        panic!("failed to create cond_attrs");
    };
    let cond_attrs = unsafe { cond_attrs.assume_init() };

    if unsafe {
        nix::libc::pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(
            &mtx_attrs as *const _ as *mut _,
            PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED,
        )
    } != 0
    {
        panic!("failed to set mtx as process shared");
    };

    if unsafe {
        nix::libc::pthread_condattr_setpshared(
            &cond_attrs as *const _ as *mut _,
            PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED,
        )
    } != 0
    {
        panic!("failed to set cond as process shared");
    };

    // I know that these offsets are correct, having used `offsetof` on the C++ side
    let mtx_start = unsafe { &raw_shm.as_slice()[3110416] };
    let mtx = unsafe { &*(mtx_start as *const _ as *const pthread_mutex_t) };
    let cond_start = unsafe { &raw_shm.as_slice()[3110440] };
    let cond = unsafe { &*(cond_start as *const _ as *const pthread_mutex_t) };

    if unsafe {
        nix::libc::pthread_mutex_init(&mtx as *const _ as *mut _, &mtx_attrs as *const _ as *mut _)
    } != 0
    {
        panic!("failed to init mtx");
    };
    if unsafe {
        nix::libc::pthread_cond_init(
            &cond as *const _ as *mut _,
            &cond_attrs as *const _ as *mut _,
        )
    } != 0
    {
        panic!("failed to init cond");
    };
```

All of that passes with return values of 0... so far so good.

I can now test it in one of two ways:

1. I can set the trivial C++ program going and have it stop waiting at the condvar:

```
if (pthread_mutex_lock(&shmp->mutex) != 0)
    throw("Error locking mutex");
if (pthread_cond_wait(&shmp->condition, &shmp->mutex) != 0)
    throw("Error waiting for condition variable");
```

and in rust:

```
let sig = unsafe { nix::libc::pthread_cond_signal(&cond as *const _ as *mut _) };
    dbg!(sig);
```

Despite returning `0` (i.e. success), my C++ program is not released past the condvar; it remains waiting as if it never received a signal.

2. I can set of another trivial C++ program which endlessly signals the condition variable in a loop:

```
    for (unsigned int count = 0;; count++) {
        if (pthread_cond_signal(condition) != 0)
            throw("Error")
        // sleep for a bit
    }
```

and then in rust, something like:

```
    loop {
        if unsafe { nix::libc::pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx as *const _ as *mut _) } > 0 {
            panic!("Failed to acquire lock")
        };
        if unsafe {
            nix::libc::pthread_cond_wait(&cond as *const _ as *mut _, &mtx as *const _ as *mut _)
        } > 0
        {
            panic!("Failed to acquire lock")
        };
    }
```

Doing it this way around, the call to lock the mutex is successful, but I get an `EINVAL` on `pthread_cond_wait` defined [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait), which I cannot seem to rectify...

I feel like I'm close... any thoughts on how to get this to work? (this is mostly just a proof of concept).

Comment: My comment won’t be really useful. Honestly, my only thought is that it’s not the best idea. Sincerely wish you good luck though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, I have managed to get this working.

To clarify how the program is architectured, there are two binaries: one C++ and one rust. The Rust program spawns the C++ program using `std::process::Command`.

Error handling and imports elided for brevity.

1. The rust program starts and creates a new shared memory block (removing an existing block if it exists, to ensure the program always starts in a fresh state). I use the [shared_memory](https://crates.io/crates/shared_memory) crate to handle the details for me, and that also provides useful helpers such as [access to a raw pointer](https://docs.rs/shared_memory/0.12.4/shared_memory/struct.Shmem.html#method.as_ptr) to the start of the memory block.

The shared memory block is structured like the following:

```rust
#[repr(c)]
struct SharedMemoryLayout {
    ready: std::sync::atomic::AtomicBool,
    mutex: libc::pthread_mutex_t,
    condition: libc::pthread_cond_t,
}
```

Shared memory blocks are initialised with zeros, so `ready` will always be `false`to begin with.

2. The rust program spawns the C++ program with `std::process::Command::spawn` and then waits in a loop until `ready` is `true`.

```rust
let proc = Command::new("/path/to/c++/binary").spawn().unwrap();

let ptr: *mut u8 = // pointer to first byte of shared memory block;
let ready: &AtomicBool =  unsafe { &*(ptr as *mut bool as *const AtomicBool) };

loop {
    if ready.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
        break
    } else {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    }
}
```

3. The C++ program opens the shared memory block and `mmap`s it into its local address space.

```cpp
struct SharedMemoryLayout
{
    std::atomic_bool ready;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t condition;
};

int fd = shm_open("name_of_shared_memory_block", O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
struct SharedMemoryLayout *sync = (SharedMemoryLayout *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(*sync), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

4. The C++ program carries on and proceeds to initialise the `mutex` and the `condition`, before marking the memory block as ready.

```cpp
pthread_mutexattr_t mutex_attributes;
pthread_condattr_t condition_attributes;

pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutex_attributes);
pthread_condattr_init(&condition_attributes);

pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutex_attributes, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
pthread_condattr_setpshared(&condition_attributes, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

pthread_mutex_init(&sync->mutex, &mutex_attributes);
pthread_cond_init(&sync->condition, &condition_attributes);

pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&mutex_attributes);
pthread_condattr_destroy(&condition_attributes);

std::atomic_bool *ready = &syncp->ready;
ready->store(true);
```

And then enter a loop signalling on the condition:

```cpp
for (unsigned int count = 0;; count++) {
    // do something
    sleep(1);
    pthread_cond_signal(&sync->condition);
}
```

5. Now, the rust program will have been released from the loop in step 2). Materialise the mutex and condition that were initialised in step 4).

```rust
let mutex = unsafe {ptr.offset(4) as *mut pthread_mutex_t};
let condition = unsafe {ptr.offset(32) as *mut pthread_cond_t};
```

And now we can wait on the condition, getting notified by the C++ program.

```rust
loop {
    unsafe {
        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
        pthread_cond_wait(condition, mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
        
        // Do something
    }
}
```